# Custom Split View for iPad, I am using a UIPopoverPresentationController. can anyone suggest me how to make it full length Popover?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover

This is my UI trying to make that Popup full length:

[image]

This is how it looks when Keyboard appears:

[image]

I want to show this in full length.

```
func present(_ viewController: UINavigationController,
                 contentSize: CGSize,
                 sourceView: UIView,
                 delegate: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate?) {

    viewController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    viewController.preferredContentSize = contentSize
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    viewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .left
    viewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
    viewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds

    viewController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = delegate

    viewController.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    viewController.view.superview?.layer.masksToBounds = true

    present(viewController, animated: true, completion: {
        viewController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want? Do you want it to go under the keyboard?

Comment: I want that to be stick at same position with full screen Height when key appears/dismissed. That should look as like as message Controller. Thanks

Comment: So the keyboard should be over/on top of the popup? Am i right?

Comment: Yes, You are correct.

Comment: Also Height of Pop should be as like as Message Controller that you see in Pic